# Getting the Microsoft SAPI Version in code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sapi

I would like to be able to get the version of SAPI that my C++ application is using, and then display it to the user.

The problem is I cannot figure out how to get the version out of the SAPI interface.

Comment: Why?  The SAPI interface version isn't that interesting; the versions of the voices or SR engines (which are independent of SAPI) would be more interesting.

Comment: I want those versions too.

Comment: Again, what is the user going to do with this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_SAPI_BUILD_VER` is a constant in sapi.h (and sapi.idl) that defines which version of SAPI you're building against.

It's based on the Win32 build version (`_WIN32_WINNT`).

For Windows 7, it's `0x054`; for Vista, it's `0x053`, and for XP, it's `0x051`.

If you need to find out at runtime, QI for interfaces that are only defined in 5.4 (`ISpRecognizer3`, for example) or 5.3 (`ISpRecognizer2`).

For voices, generally speaking, the available voices change depending on the installed version.

Comment: What if it's built on a Windows 7 machine and then run on a Windows XP machine, will it be using 5.4 functionality? or 5.1?